# How to select item in an unordered list during crawling?

Tags: python, html, xpath, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I would like to crawl a specific element of an HTML page that is inside an unordered list. Sometimes, this element is present, sometimes it isn't. If the element is present, I want to select the second paragraph in the respective list item.

Example:

```
<div class="testdiv">
  <ul class="ullist">
    <li><p>random element 1</p><p>value</p></li>
    <li><p>random element 2</p><p>value</p></li> 
    <li><p>element_to_select</p><p>wanted_value</p></li> 
    <li><p>random element 4</p><p>value</p></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

For the HTML above, I first want to check if 'element_to_select' is present, and if yes, get wanted_value.

I have tried the following (rather naive) approach:

```
soup_parsed = BeautifulSoup(global_html.encode('utf-8'), 'html.parser')
index_of_wanted_element = self.index_containing_substring([str(s) for s in soup_parsed.find_all("p")], "element_to_select")
wanted_element_paragraph = soup_parsed.find_all("p")[index_of_wanted_element+1]
wanted_value_string = str(wanted_element_paragraph).replace("<p>","").replace("</p>","")
```

in which index_containing_substring finds the index of the wanted string in a list.

Is this possible in Python, e.g., using BeautifulSoup, Xpath, etc.?

Comment: Please add that code to your question. There's better formatting tools there :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to get the `element_to_select` element by text, check if it is not `None` and, if not, get the next `p` sibling element:

```
element_to_select = soup.find("p", text="element_to_select")
if element_to_select is not None:
    next_element = element_to_select.find_next_sibling("p")
    print(next_element.get_text())
```